# Making layout work in IE8 quirks mode

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, quirks-mode

A third party product outputs a webpage with iframes and I'm not in full control of the content. The main iframe is missing doctype declaration and this forces IE8 into quirks mode.

I'm maintaining a javascript application that adds several buttons to the right edge of the screen. The problem is that the layout is off in IE8 quirks mode. The buttons are not visible (probably due to incorrect IE z-index behavior) and their position is off.

I was thinking about creating a separate CSS for IE8. How should I go about tuning the CSS for quirks mode?

Comment: Use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

Comment: @robertc - If he were able to set conditional comments, wouldn't he also be able to set a doctype?

Comment: @FrankConijn My understanding is: he controls the page with the buttons but not the page loaded in the `iframe`.

Comment: @robertc - OK, but wouldn't he have to set the conditional comments on the page loaded into the iframe?

Comment: @FrankConijn He wants to apply an additional CSS file to his buttons in IE, so that's where he'd need to add the conditional comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do have control over the (separate) Javascript files, and presuming that a JS file is already called in the head, you could set a conditional class on the `html` element, like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo Conditional Class Quirks Mode</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="folder/js_file.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    div {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: red;
        position: relative;
        left: 100px;
        }
    .ieQM div {
        left: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

While adding this to the js_file.js:

```
if (document.documentMode == 5)
    document.documentElement.className += ' ieQM'; // IE in Quirks Mode
```

.
By the way, I wonder whether it is just a problem in IE8, the document not having a doctype? Don't all IEs revert to quirks mode without it?